# How to enrich/extend Auth class/data in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, authentication

In Laravel it's very useful to access Auth Facade after authentication in order to get user data like:

```
Auth::user()
```

What If during session and users interaction I'd like to enrich the object returned by the above call? Maybe assign some attributes to a user after he performed some action on my webapp?

E.g. A user performs a fast registration, and after while completes some other profile data. I'd like them to be available directly in Auth::user() instead of perform subsequent DB queries...

**IMPORTANT**
I'm integrating Auth0 into Laravel authentication. So the default driver/provider behind Auth is not Eloquent but Auth0.

Auth0 gives back a Json object containing all authenticated data.

```
Auth0User->userInfo
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to edit the Auth data after Auth0 Authentication by adding custom data to Session Object.

Basically I want to use another service to manage account related data, and use Auth0 only for managing user/password grant.

Comment: You should be getting the updated user object on each request using `Auth::user`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom attribute to the User model. For example:

```
public function getTestAttribute()
{
    return session()->get('test', 'defaultValue');
}
```

It is possible to set the session key somewhere else in your application:

```
session()->put('test', 'otherValue');
```